# How can I produce a hex-escaped string in python that I can use in C++?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create synthesized unit tests for a library that uses MessagePack. I would like to create hex-escaped binary strings in python that I can embed in C++ sources. I'm creating one like this:

```
In [6]: umsgpack.packb([0, 0, 'dummy_void_zeroarg', []])
Out[6]: '\x94\x00\x00\xc4\x12dummy_void_zeroarg\x90'
```

However, it looks like the resulting hex string is almost, but not quite usable in C++:

```
error: hex escape sequence out of range
        "\x94\x00\x00\xc4\x12dummy_void_zeroarg\x90";
                         ^~~~~
```

The reason is that the compiler tries to parse `\x12d` as a single value. Is there a way to transform the above hex string to one in python that does not contain letters (i.e. only `\x` items)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do so manually:

```
"'{}'".format(''.join(['\\x{:02x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in message]))
```

Print the result or write it to a file:

```
>>> print "'{}'".format(''.join(['\\x{:02x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in message]))
'\x94\x00\x00\xc4\x12\x64\x75\x6d\x6d\x79\x5f\x76\x6f\x69\x64\x5f\x7a\x65\x72\x6f\x61\x72\x67\x90'
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use initialization list with `char` literals, like this one:

```
char abc[] = {'\x41', 'B', 'C', 0};
```

So relevant python code for generating initializer would be:

```
print("{{{}, 0}}".format(', '.join(map(repr, source_string))))
```

So for your string I get:

```
{'\x94', '\x00', '\x00', 'Ä', '\x12', 'd', 'u', 'm', 'm', 'y', '_', 'v', 'o', 'i', 'd', '_', 'z', 'e', 'r', 'o', 'a', 'r', 'g', '\x90', 0}
```

Comment: There is a stray `"` at the start there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oops, that's from `repr`, missed that one. There's easy fix, but now that feels extra hacky.

Comment: Note that you could've used `%r` to get a `repr()` output rather than call `repr()` explicitly.

Comment: Why not use `"{%s, 0}" % ', '.join(map(repr, source_string))`? And you want to look into `str.format()` too, rather than use the older and less flexible `%` string formatting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I wouldn't dare to assume that calling `map` per character would be a good idea performance-wise. Does CPython inline `repr` call then? I'd expect to be slow with bigger strings. As for "%r", that would suffer from the same quotation problem, sadly, but thanks for that one - I didn't know that. As for `str.format()` - yeah, I'll replace.

Comment: Yes, using a loop with `repr` is a O(n) approach. But so is `str.join()` on the source string. Both loops are entirely executed in C however.

Comment: Complexity-wise, yes. I was thinking in terms of stack-frames/call-frames (C habits). I'll have to run `timeit` and see.

Comment: Unless your are *predominantly* producing strings like these, the difference won't matter because you are running *Python code* to generate text. This probably doesn't need to be optimised to this extend, or even make enough of a difference to warrant the work to figure this out, then in future, as you maintain the code, figure out *again* why you made these choices.