# Converting a string to Hex in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, hex

How can I convert a string like "AAAA" to "/x41/x41/x41/x41" hex format in python ?
There are many functions like binascii.hexlify and all, but those just converts it to 41414141, how can I get the /x in-front to every converted byte ?

EDIT: Need to convert "AAAA" to "\x41\x41\x41\x41" in byte type. Sorry, included Wrong slash in the question.

Comment: There is probably a tool to do it directly, but as alternative you also add the `/x` yourself using a `join` and `format`. `f"/x{'/x'.join('{:02x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in 'AAAA')}"` should do the trick.

Comment: Alternative answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275085/python-string-to-escaped-hex), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975528/how-can-i-produce-a-hex-escaped-string-in-python-that-i-can-use-in-c), and another way using joining `''.join(list(hex(ord(c)) for c in "AAAA")).replace('0x', '/x')`.

Comment: Adding /x manually using join, the output becomes a string,, I need the output as a byte. By converting the output to byte adds an extra / in-front of the existing / (slash).

Comment: Thank you bro,    ```f"/x{'/x'.join('{:02x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in 'AAAA')}" ```   worked even after converting the output to byte using    ```str.encode(output) ```   . Probably using    ```format```    has something to do with it. I was just using    ```join ```   . Would be really helpful if you could explain why your code worked and didn't add an extra slash after byte encoding.

Comment: I am not sure why it didn't work for you. Both of the join methods that I showed above work for me (first one with format and second without). The only sane thought I have got about encodings is that it is a lot of work if you don't use `utf-8`.

Comment: @Thymen, sorry bro included wrong slash in the question, I need it to convert to "\x41\x41\x41\x41". Can not use \ in join and format, python gives unicodeescape error.

Comment: In that case making it a raw string would work `r"\x"` or using an escape char `"\\x"` should work. `print(''.join(hex(ord(c)) for c in "AAAA").replace('0x', '\\x'))` will be `\x41\x41\x41\x41`.

Answer (score 0):

I did not had to include \x in front of every byte. Python `unhexlify` did it automatically I guess.

```
Input = "AAAA"
Input = str.encode(Input)
Input = hexlify(Input)
Input = unhexlify(Input) #If you print it, it will just print b'AAAA'
```

Then sent the input with something like this and it worked, I did not had to include \x.

`SendInput = b'\x01\x01\x00\x02' + Input`